# How to assign android app XML Layouts corresponding to device size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

how to make android app with *XML layouts* for some type of devices and activities for another, let's say i want the app to use a certain *XML activity layout* for the devices that it's size from **3'** inches to **5'** inches and to use another for the devices from **7'** inches  to **10'** inches. for my example in my app I have like 10 Activities each one has an XML layout for the **10'** devices, and now I want to make another layout for the devices from **3'** to **7'** and programatically nothing will change.
also I want the first bunch of layouts to be landscaped and the other ones to be portrait.

I found that [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html/) but I don't want android to make the screen detect work by it's own as I'm not sure that it will understand the way I created my layouts by as it's not just a small and big one but the whole structure is different.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602726/supporting-all-screen-sizes-in-android/22603668#22603668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

besides the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602726/supporting-all-screen-sizes-in-android/22603668#22603668) that @KanwaljitSingh provide in the comments, I found also that [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) that explains all the ways to achieve that purpose.